# For a mixed hodge structure, what is the exact condition on the graded pieces?

Tags: hodge-theory, hodge-structure

A mixed ($\mathbb{Q}$)-hodge structure is defined to be a vector space $V/\mathbb{Q}$ with an  increasing "weight" filtration of $\mathbb{Q}$- vector spaces $0\subset W_0\subset \dots$ and a decreasing "Hodge" Filtration of complex vector spaces $V=F^0\supset F^1\dots$ such that the following holds:

On the quotient pieces $W_{i+1}/W_i$ on gets an induced filtration 
$$F^p(W_{i}/W_{i-1}):=(W_{i}\cap F^p + W_{i-1}\otimes\mathbb{C})/(W_{i-1}\otimes\mathbb{C})$$
and everyone writes that this induced filtration is "pure of weight $i$".

My question is what precisely does this mean? Initially I thought it meant that (for the piece $W_{i}/W_{i-1}$ the relation $F^j\oplus\overline{F^{i+1-j}}=W_{i}/W_{i-1}$ holds, but this seems to be false for basic cases such as the limit mixed hodge structure on the nearby cycles of a family of elliptic curves degenerating to a nodal cubic.

Any references to thorough and clear definitions would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Deligne's *Théorie de Hodge II* (Pub. Math. IHÉS 40 (1971), 5-57) is perfectly clear.

Comment: could you please reference a lemma or page number?

Comment: Définition 2.3.1 p. 30. But the whole paper is focussed on this notion.

Comment: Ok, so he gives the definition as I interpreted it... then perhaps could you please explain the mixed hodge structure of the nodal cubic to me? I might just post this is a separate question as this appears to be the source of my confusion.

Comment: Ok, so doesn't this mean that $W_0=F^0=F^1$ in this case? So I'm confused because it seems that on the weight 0 graded piece (which is just $i(\mathbb{C})$ the induced filtration is $F^0Gr^0W = Gr^0W, F^1Gr^0W=Gr^0W,F^2Gr^0W=0$. But isn't this supposed ton be a hodge structure of weight 0?

Comment: You are right, I was too hasty in the definition of $F^1$. The point is that $H^0(N,\Omega ^1_N)$ lifts naturally to $H^1(C,\mathbb{C})=\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(C,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{C}) $. THis gives $F^1$, and $F^1\cap W_0=(0)$.

Comment: ... see for instance §3.$b$ of Carlson's *Extensions of mixed Hodge structures*, in *Journées de géométrie algébrique d'Angers*, Sijthof and Noordhof (1980).

Comment: Ah, thats super helpful, thanks!
So one of the sources of my confusion is resolved by the realization that limit mixed hodge structures can't be defined until you pick a tangent direction.